# How to Upload Photos with text in same request?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I m using Eclipse / Android - Facebook SDK and i need to upload Photos with text at same request. There is a sample in SDK but it post Photos without any text to explain the picture.

Any body know how to do that ?

Answer (score 10):

I'm programming android and facebook sdk in a week and, as nobody answer my question and includind vote against my post i solve the SDK limitation by my self and add a method to implement ulpload of photos with captions. bellow the solution:

Insert this code into com.facebook -> request.java

```
public static Request newMyUploadPhotoRequest(Session session,  Bitmap image, String caption,String description,
        Callback callback)  {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle(3);
    parameters.putParcelable(PICTURE_PARAM, image);
    parameters.putString("caption",caption);
    parameters.putString("description",description );

    return new Request(session, MY_PHOTOS, parameters, HttpMethod.POST, callback);


}
```

Call method from your activity

```
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        Request request = Request.newMyUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image,"Teste Caption", "teste description", new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                showPublishResult(getString(R.string.photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
            }
        });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Comment: I don't know why the votes against your post. I have upvoted them

Comment: This solution works. Might make more sense to create your own method in a file that wont be wiped when you update the SDK...

Comment: What is "PICTURE_PARAM"?

Comment: geniooo!! you make my day